# sending $.post to .aspx using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, email-validation, .post

I started the jQuery tutorial made by phpAcademy on thenewboston youtube channel.
I reached the part where I have to create an email validation form BUT, I am not using PHP, I am using ASP.net for this tutorial.

So, the thing is that even though I did everything as said in the tutorial, I can't send any variable to the .aspx page by using $.post and when I want to retrieve the variable from the .aspx page, it retrieves me the entire source code.

The source code for the Main page:

```
<input type="text" id="email" /> <span id="emailfeed"></span>
```

Javascript file with jQuery code:

```
function validate_email(email) {
        $.post('email.aspx', { email: email }, function (data) {
            $('#emailfeed').text(data);

        });
    }

    $('#email').focusin(function () {
        if ($('#email').val() === '') {
            $('#emailfeed').text('Enter your email here');
        } else {
            validate_email($('#email').val());
        }
    }).blur(function () {
        $('#emailfeed').text('');
    }).keyup(function () {
        validate_email($('#email').val());
    });
```

The email.aspx.cs code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {

        string email = Request.Form["email"];
        emailLabel.Text = email;// HTTP Post
        }
    }
```

What this code does is to send everything I type in the field to the email.aspx and then retrieve what arrived in the email.aspx and showing it in the span tag "emailfeed".
So basically, what I write in the email field it should be displayed between the span tags... but this doesn't happen and instead that, I get this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head><title>

 </title></head>
 <body>
 <form method="post" action="email.aspx" id="form1">
 <div class="aspNetHidden">
 <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="6/oBNs2tFeYkrpkFpDL724BXcQwQ8axaBMe/+VEr/27lNqbjE1FyzyK6Zrl2TCcvjgfkv01vyV3PXehcal8bJZdEfpf4v5KkxQTelnzKhlM=" />
 </div>

 <div>
 <span id="emailLabel"></span>
 </div>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

So basically this is the source code of the email.aspx showing up between  instead of what I'm actually typing.

How can I sort this out?

Comment: I would also would like to mention that I know that now this validation can be easily done by HTML5, but I just want to figure it out why is this not working. $.get is, as well, not working for me so I'd like to figure it out if it's because of me doing something wrong or what am I missing.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that sort of strange behaviour before, the showing of the page source. I seem to recall it was due to the ajax call returning a contentType that confuses the ASP.NET framework. Try setting the `dataType` of the `$.post` to `html`.

Comment: Ok, you are totally right about this and now it displays nothing (it works). But the thing is that jQuery is not passing the variable "email" to my .aspx file by post. What am I doing wrong? Why my .aspx file doesn't receive the information sent by $.post()?

Comment: You answer only solves half of my problem... if you could help me with rest of it, it would be great... I spent already 3 hours trying to making this work and I didn't achieve a positive result...

Comment: I think your form data may not be showing up because your JSON is not formatted correctly. Try `{ "email": "email" }`